# Windows 8.1 does not load on my dual boot laptop

Tags: ubuntu, windows, dual-boot

I installed Ubuntu on my laptop which has already Windows 8.1 on it. I can't use windows anymore.

Below is my configuration for the Windows 8.1 booty loading. The link of windows OS appears in boot menu, but when I click on it, it redirects back to the boot menu.

```
    setparams 'windows 8 (loader) (on/dev/seda1)'
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ntfs
    set root='hdo,msdos1'
    if[x$feature_platform_search_hint=xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1 AA36FA8236FAF37
    else
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root AA36FA8236FAF37
    fi
    drivemap -s (hd0) ${root}enter code here
    chainloader +1
```

Comment: Please [edit] and clarify: 1) What file are you showing? 2) Are those the exact contents of the file? You show `on /dev/seda1` and `${root}enter code here`, did you copy/paste the file directly? 3) Can you boot into Linux? If so, does running `sudo update-grub` help?